# Why is $A=\{\eta\in 2A-1\}$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

> If $\eta=1-|2x-1|$ on $[0,1]$ and $A\subset[0,1]$ s.t. $A=1-A$ why is $A=\{\eta\in 2A-1\}$

$\eta$ is symmetric about $1/2$, i.e. $\eta(x)=\eta(1-x)$, so say $x\in A$ and $x<1/2$ then $\eta$ becomes $1-(1-2x)=2x$ which means that $\exists y\in A$ s.t. $2x=2y-1$ (if the sets are equal) this is equivalent to say that for any $1/2>x\in A$, one has $x+1/2\in A$, is this possible ?

Comment: The notation $\{\eta\in 2A-1\}$ is not standard.  What is $A=\{\eta\in 2A-1\}$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @EricWofsey It appears in a stochastic book, so $\{\eta\in2A-1\}=\{w:\eta(w)\in 2A-1\}$ I think

Comment: If $A = \{0,1\}$, isn't $\frac{1}{2}$ in the RHS since $\eta(1/2) = 1$? (Or do you mean $\{w\in A\,:\,\eta(w)\in 2A-1\}$?)

Comment: Or, let $A = \{1/8, 7/8\}$; then $\eta(A) = \{1/4\}$ so that $\{w\in A\,:\,\eta(w)\in 2A-1\} = \emptyset$.